# Why pandas max function does not return the right max date?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, datetime, max

I wanted to get the max date from a column in a DataFrame, but the results are wrong?
What I am doing wrong?

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'date':['31.12.2014', '03.10.2015','02.01.2013', '05.01.2013', '14.10.2015']})
```

the result of `df.date.max()` is `'31.12.2014'` and not `'14.10.2015'`? why?

Comment: Looks like it's sorting them as strings, without knowing that those strings represent dates?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True).max()  ` does the job.

Answer (score 3):

First convert your date column to datetime format, and then check for max or min values

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'date':['31.12.2014', '03.10.2015','02.01.2013', '05.01.2013', '14.10.2015']})

# Convert to datetime format
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Print max value
print(df['date'].max())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the strings to be compared as a datetime object this should help.

```
df['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]').max()
```